# Second Order Partial Derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, physics

I have a partial derivative: 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \varepsilon}$$
I want to find the second order partial derivative $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}$, and online I found the answer as:
$$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \varepsilon^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \varepsilon\zeta}+\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \zeta^2}$$
Can someone explain how they arrived at this?

If it's of any relevance, this is dealing with the 1-D wave equation and it's coming from [here](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.08f/lec17.pdf) (equations 6 and 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon} \right) u
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u =&\ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon} \right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon} \right) u = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon} \right)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \varepsilon}\right) \\
=&\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \varepsilon}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \varepsilon}\right) \\
=&\ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\zeta^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \zeta\partial \varepsilon} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \varepsilon^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just a question, what exactly does it mean to write $\frac {\partial} {\partial \zeta}$ on its own (i.e. $\frac {\partial} {\partial \zeta}$ + $\frac {\partial} {\partial \varepsilon}$)? I understand $\frac {\partial u} {\partial \zeta}$.

Comment: When I rewrite $\partial/\partial \zeta$ I am viewing the object as an operator  which acts on functions $u$ (like a matrix acting on a vector, i.e. $A(x) = Ax$).